# Why local notification is repeated after 1 minute when the repeat interval is set 1 sec(NSSecCalendarUnit)?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I am trying to schedule a local notificaition that will repeat after every 1 sec once the notification is fired. The notification is fired 10 sec after the application starts.

```
UILocalNotification *notif = [[cls alloc] init];

    notif.fireDate = [[NSDate alloc]initWithTimeInterval:10 sinceDate:[NSDate date]];
    notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notif.alertBody = @"Did you forget something?";
    notif.alertAction = @"Show me";
    //notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notif.soundName = @"applause-light-01.wav";
    notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    notif.repeatInterval = NSSecondCalendarUnit;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
```

Even thought I have used `notif.repeatInterval = NSSecondCalendarUnit`, notification repeat after 60 sec. What is that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Not really familiar with the iOS calendar, but the first thing that comes to mind is Apple putting a limit in place to keep you from notifying the user more than once per minute.

Comment: I had this problem too. I think they don't allow you to spam users with notifications like you do....

Answer (score 1):

```
notif.fireDate = [[NSDate alloc]initWithTimeInterval:10 sinceDate:[NSDate date]];
```

This line of code makes your local notification to fire after the new date is created. If you want the notifications right away then you should just create a simple date like this,

```
notif.fireDate = [NSDate date];
```

Hope this helps.