# I am trying to fire local notification every 5 seconds using this code

Tags: ios, iphone, uilocalnotification, localnotification

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (localNotification == nil)
    return;
//localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:timeInterval sinceDate:now];
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
localNotification.repeatInterval = 5*NSSecondCalendarUnit;
localNotification.alertBody = @"Your alert message";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

This code generates notification after first 5 second then it goes back to NSMinuteCalendarUnit, I have been trying to work around with this but no help.

I want to set notifications every 5 seconds and then it should fire it until i forcefully want to stop it.

Can somebody please help??

Comment: Take a look at this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644357/why-local-notification-is-repeated-after-1-minute-when-the-repeat-interval-is-se

Answer (score 4):

The [`repeatInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009565-CH1-SW3) of a [`UILocalNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is of type `NSCalendarUnit` not an time interval. You can only assign a value from the [`NSCalendarUnit`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001451-SW2) enum to it.

If you want to fire a local notification every 5 seconds you will need to set multiple notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code.
Use this for every 5 minutes instead of every week.

```
-(void)setLocalNotificationwithOptions :(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
     UILocalNotification *localNoti = [launchOptions  objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
if (localNoti) {
    NSLog(@"Notification:%@",localNoti);
}

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

NSCalendar *gregCalendar12 = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *dateComponent12 = [gregCalendar12 components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];


[dateComponent12 setWeekday:7];
[dateComponent12 setHour:14];
[dateComponent12 setMinute:46];

UILocalNotification *notification12 = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[notification12 setAlertBody:@"ENJOY YOUR WEEKEND!"];
[notification12 setFireDate:[gregCalendar12 dateFromComponents:dateComponent12]];
notification12.repeatInterval = NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
[notification12 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification12];
}
```

Hope this helps you. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

if you want to repeat the timer every 5 seconds,
UILocalNotification allows until 30 seconds per one sound.
So put a 30 seconds sound in your directory,
and then

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
NSDate *date = "set your notification date"
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    NSDate *repeatTime = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:300 * i];
    notification.fireDate = repeatTime;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```